# Magento Extra tabs not displaying images

Tags: magento, tabs, imageurl, dynamic-url

I have an extension called TB Extra Tabs installed. It allows me to add extra tabs to the products front end, next to the description and review tabs.

The images I place into the description appear fine, but the pics in this new tab dont.

The wysiwig changes the url to this:  src="{{media url="wysiwyg/MyFAN/lighting.JPG"}}"

But on the front end it comes out as:

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got the short tags for that enabled in Magento admin?

Answer (score 0):

Okay worked it out.

I replaced:

```
<?php echo $value; ?>
```

With:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($value);?>
```